# UIWebview does not work like Native iPhone Browser when interacting with ASPX page

Tags: iphone, asp.net, ios, browser, uiwebview

I am fairly new to iphone development and I've been trying to create a "wrapper" app that points to a ASPX webpage. The webpage loads without any issues in my UIWebview and the user can select items from two dropdown boxes.

The issue here is that once the user selects an item from the dropdown menu, the page should refresh to reflect the selected value. This does not happen in my webview but works correctly in Safari on my iphone.

Here's the link to the webpage so you can see what I'm talking about: [here](http://busmobile.streeteagleweb.com/Default.aspx?Key=mb3r7jscvaullCg4)

My question is.. what are the differences between a uiwebview and the native browser which affect running JS or ASPX or other webpage contents AND how do I fix this issue?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The user agents sent by Safari and UIWebView are different, so your problem might be related to this: [UIWebview and IPhone content does not postback (ASP.NET Browser Capability issues)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7275695/uiwebview-and-iphone-content-does-not-postback-asp-net-browser-capability-issue)

Answer (score 1):

Just to keep others updated, the only answers I could find regarding this issue is found on:
http://www.tuaw.com/2011/03/18/apple-confirms-some-webkit-optimizations-unavailable-to-ios-apps/

AND

http://drnicwilliams.com/2008/11/10/to-webkit-or-not-to-webkit-within-your-iphone-app/

Apparently Apple limits what users can do on a uiwebview as opposed to the Safari Mobile browser. Also, the second link says that JS is one directional. If anyone has a work around to my problem, it would be greatly appreciated!!