# Iphone UIWebView not working on javascript buttons

Tags: javascript, iphone, objective-c, ios, uiwebview

I want to try load a private webpage in uiwebview. 
When I try to open it from the native Safari app on my iPhone,  everything works well.

But when I try to open in uiwebvie, the buttons on the webpage doesn't work. 
Buttons are as follows

```
<a class="actionButtonWithoutImg" href="javascript:__doPostBack('','')">Edit</a>
```

Do you have any idea ?

Comment: Please provide the rest of the markup on the page if possible. is `__doPostBack('','')` defined in the file you are loading? is it loaded from an external js file?

also i would recommend you mark up those links in this manner: `<a href="#" onclick="javascriptFunction();">link</a>`

Comment: Thank You Ben. Javascript is not defined in external file. But i tried in another page 
`<a href="#" onclick="javascriptFunction();">link</a>`
and
`href="javascript:__doPostBack('','')"` 
both of them are working. 
I don't understand the problem...

Comment: so is the problem solved from that change..?

Comment: Unfortunately. I'm working on it. Not solved.

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET? See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7275695/uiwebview-and-iphone-content-does-not-postback-asp-net-browser-capability-issue