# JQuery JConfirm not working with UIWebview on iOS

Tags: jquery, ios, uiwebview

We have an iOS app that uses a UIWebView control to display a web page.  The web page uses JQuery to display a jConfirm confirmation dialog.  When the user presses the cancel button, it does not respond.  The Javascript is supposed to issue a postback to our asp.net page to process the cancel.  It works fine on Safari/iPhone, Chrome/Android, and even in an Android/WEbview native app.  but it does not work on an iPhone native app using UIWebView.

Below is a code snip of our call to JConfirm and the DoPostback when they press cancel.
We are on JQuery 1.6.4.  Anybody know if this a known issue with JConfirm and the UIWEbView control?  Thanks, Dan

```
    function showCancelDialog() {
        //set up the confirmation dialog
        $.alerts.okButton = "Yes";
        $.alerts.cancelButton = "No";
        $.alerts.buttonStyle = "font-size:medium; border-bottom: 1px solid #666688; border-right: 1px solid #666688; border-left: 1px solid #eaeaea;  border-top: 1px solid #eaeaea; background-color: #dCdBd6;";
        $.alerts.overlayOpacity = 0.7;

        //confirm to cancel or not
        jConfirm('Your payment will be cancelled. <br> Continue to cancel?', 'Cancel Payment?', function (r) {

            if (r) {
                //they have pressed Yes.
                //now force a server side post back on the asp.net Cancel button
                __doPostBack($(cancelButton).attr('name'), '');
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        })

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Update:  I found the answer to this issue on another SO blog entry.

[UIWebview and IPhone content does not postback (ASP.NET Browser Capability issues)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7275695/uiwebview-and-iphone-content-does-not-postback-asp-net-browser-capability-issue)

In a nutshell, solution is to set the @Page level directive ClientTarget = "uplevel" or do it in page load with code behind.

Side note, I couldn't figure out how to put ClientTarget in a web.config to make it happen site wide.  If anybody figures that out, please post solution here.