# iPad 6_0_1 ScriptManager.SupportsPartialRendering ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, ajax, ipad, scriptmanager

We started to receive the below error a few months ago, it looks like mac os 6. Can someone help me shed some light on the below issue? We have a lot of partial rendering on our site, but it seems asp.net thinks ipad 6_0_1 cannot handle it.

Event Target: ctl00$ScriptManager1

Exception: System.Web.HttpUnhandledException (0x80004005): Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The page is performing an async postback but the ScriptManager.SupportsPartialRendering property is set to false. Ensure that the property is set to true during an async postback. at System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.OnPageInitComplete(Object sender, EventArgs e) at System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e) at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e) at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest() at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

User Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 6_0_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Mobile/10A523 Safari/8536.25

Comment: I'm having this problem too - it looks like the ASP.NET browser detection is failing to recognize that anything higher than iOS 6.0.0 doesn't support XmlHttpRequest. Other UA strings causing problems are: Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 6_1_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/10B146, Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 6_1_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/10B146

Comment: IF you inherit all your pages from a custom base page you can override the OnPreInit method to check if the useragent contains AppleWebKit and, if so, set the ClientTarget property to "uplevel". This didn't work in my situation as we use a few different page base classes (some outside our code hence I can't change it) but it **might** fix yours see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7275695/uiwebview-and-iphone-content-does-not-postback-asp-net-browser-capability-issue

Answer (score 0):

Since I've been working on this all day I thought I'd post what I ended up doing in addition to my above comments. It looks like the important browser capabilities are

```
ecmascriptversion=1.5
w3cdomversion=1.0
supportscallback=true
```

If any one of these aren't present the Sys.WebForms object won't get created.

I ended up creating a custom browser file in the App_Browsers folder:

```
<browsers>
   <gateway id="IPad" parentID="Safari">
      <identification>
         <userAgent match="iPad" />
      </identification>

      <capabilities>
         <capability name="ecmascriptversion" value="1.5" />
         <capability name="w3cdomversion" value="1.0" />
         <capability name="supportscallback" value="true" />
         <capability name="supportsxmlhttp" value="true" />
      </capabilities>
   </gateway>
</browsers>
```

The last capability is not necessary for creation of the Sys.WebForms object however I'm not quite sure how Ajax is supposed to work *without* an XMLHttpRequest object.