# ASP4.5.1, Bootstrap, w/AJAX Control Toolkit Throw ScriptManager Error on iOS Browsers

Tags: ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have a newly upgraded application at www.cougarsbaseballsoftball.com that works fine on IE and Chrome on a PC but is failing on Safari and Chrome on iOS8 devices. On pageload it fails producing the message, “The control with ID upnlMessage (an update panel) requires a ScriptManager on the page. The ScriptManager must appear before any controls that need it.”

The scriptmanager, a version provided, via the AJAX control toolkit, is in the masterpage:
    
        
        
            All of the script references go here…

```
    </ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>
```

I have tried the following solutions from related posts but have not found a workable solution:

1.Create an App_Browser file to handle requests from iPads: [iPad 6_0_1 ScriptManager.SupportsPartialRendering ASP.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14635631/ipad-6-0-1-scriptmanager-supportspartialrendering-asp-net).  This did not correct the iOS inter-op issue, but caused no impact to browsers on PCs. This change was rolled-back.
2. Create an App_Browser file to handle requests for Safari browsers (presumably across platform): [iOS 8 / Safari 8 not working with ASP.NET AJAX-Extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25978746/ios-8-safari-8-not-working-with-asp-net-ajax-extensions). This did not correct the iOS inter-op issue. It caused application failure on the PC browsers.  This change was rolled-back.
3. Add EnablePartialRendering and LoadScritsBeforeUI attributes to the ToolkitScriptManager declaration (see above) - [The ScriptManager must appear before any controls that need it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13473808/the-scriptmanager-must-appear-before-any-controls-that-need-it) - Chris Bint’s point near the bottom.  This change was left in the application.

The site is running on a GoDaddy Ultimate site with trust level = full. Although the site is running on framework 4.5.1 the problem can be replicated on 4.5.0.  I have not tried to revert to 4.0 due to interdependency issues with the Ajax Control Toolkit.

Answer (score 3):

Check to see if you have a `Site.Mobile.master` and a `ViewSwitcher.ascx` in your solution.

I ran into this problem and discovered that when trying to view the application on a mobile device it was actually switching to the mobile master which didn't have a script manager.  I am using a responsive web design and decided to exclude the mobile master and ViewSwitcher which solved my problem.

Hope this will work for you as well.

Happy New Year.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, my error.  First responsive application so I did not consider Site.Mobile.Master.  I put in redirect code to by pass it's use in the onLoad() event; However, I still needed to put the Ajax Control Toolkit script manager in the Site.Mobile.Master page to avoid the error.

Thanks for your help!